# How to extract Dynamic Countdown timer value from a webpage?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage which has a timer which runs from 2:35 to 0:0
I want to extract the timer current value using BeautifulSoup

Markup:

```
<div class="c_draw_w" ng-click="globalsicBoCtlr.sicBoDrawsFun(globalsicBoCtlr.sicBoDraws[0])">
    <span>
        <span class="ng-binding">#338</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ng-binding">4:54PM</span>
    <span>
        <span class="ng-binding">01:33</span>
    </span>

</div>
```

I am using this code to extract the time:

```
    time_left = page_soup.find('div',{'class':'c_draw_w'}).findChildren('span', recursive=False)[2].text
print(time_left)
```

The result I get is:

```
{{globalsicBoCtlr.RemMinutes}}:{{globalsicBoCtlr.RemSeconds}}
```

How to get the current time that is displayed on the UI?

Comment: use XPath in the inspect element and get it in the python by XPath from the webpage.

Comment: please include the url. We need to understand how the page dynamically adds info if that is the case.